# What Scala packages does Spark automatically import?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The scala documentation [says](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/packaging-imports.html) that `java.lang.*` and `scala.*` are automatically imported when starting a session. Therefore, when starting a spark-shell (v2.4.0), I assumed that

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
```

is not necessary for using the Regex class. However, when I do not import `scala.util.matching.Regex`, the spark-shell throws an error:

```
scala> val my_regex = new Regex(".*")
<console>:23: error: not found: type Regex
```

Interestingly, what does work is

```
 scala> val my_regex = ".*".r
 my_regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*
```

Questions:

1. What is imported automatically when starting a spark-shell?
2. Why is the Regex class available when using the second approach?

Comment: importing `scala._` means anything under `scala` package, Regex is under `scala.util.matching`, not `scala`. About your second question, you don't need to import the resulting type of a method to be able to call that method, in almost every programming language.

Comment: _"I assumed that `import scala.util.matching.Regex` is not necessary"_, no idea why you assumed that, as you said the docs say that `scala.*` is imported; not `scala.util.matching.*` - _"What is imported automatically when starting a spark-shell?"_, AFAIK the same as any **Scala** shell / file but also some **Spark** goodies like `sc` _(a `SparkContext`)_ and `spark` _(a `SparkSession`)_ - _"Why is the Regex class available when using the second approach"_, is not, what is available is an extension method `.r` on any `String` that does return a `Regex`; such method is defined in `Predef`

Comment: @AminMal I don't understand: why is `scala.util.matching.Regex` not under `scala`? It literally is.

Comment: When you import everything inside a package, you import everything **directly** under that package, `scala.util.matching.Regex` is not **directly** under `scala` package.

Comment: In **Scala** imports are only aliases _(well, implicits are a bit more complex than this but in essence is also about aliases)_ So when yo do `import foo.bar.baz.Quax` and then you use `Quax` then all the compiler does is replace that `Quax` with the full name. As such, when the docs say that everything inside `scala` is imported it includes only those things directly in that namespace, not recursively since the compiler can't really do that.

Comment: You could, however, say `new util.matching.Regex(...)` (not that that's particularly idiomatic in most Scala codebases), since `scala.util` would be available as just `util`.

Comment: As for the second question, the `r` method on a `String` is implicitly added through an implicit conversion to `StringOps` (IIRC), and that conversion is imported along with `scala.*`.